# Call php file which includes JS code from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to call PHP file (ad.php) from javascript in order to show ad between video and download button, but it didn't work. This PHP file includes Adsense code (JS code)

Javascript

```
 function download(u) {
   const l = ['oniano.fbkk22-3.fna.jhjdf.net', 'scontent-lga3-1.hfhukkk.com'];
   return u.replace(/(^http).*(v\/)/, `https://${l[Math.floor(l.length*Math.random())]}/v/`);
 }

 //alert('<?php echo $url; ?>');
 $.getJSON('<?php echo $url; ?>', function(data) {
   let getContents = data.graphql.shortcode_media
   let chk = false
   let display = []
   if (getContents.is_video) {
     $('.content').append('<a target="_blank" href="' + download(getContents.video_url) + '&dl=1"><img width="100%" src="' + getContents.display_url + '"></a><br><br>')
     $('.content').append( <?php include("./inc/ad.php");?>)
     $('.content').append('<a target="_blank" class="gemiano gemiano-large center" href="' + download(getContents.video_url) + '&dl=1">Download file</a><br>')
     $('.content').append('')
     display.push(getContents.display_url)
     chk = true
     inject();
   } else if (getContents.edge_sidecar_to_children === undefined) {
     let lastItem = getContents.display_resources[getContents.display_resources.length-1].src
     $('.content').append('<a target="_blank" href=' + download(lastItem) + '&dl=1"><img width="100%" src="' + lastItem + '"></a><br><br>')
     $('.content').append('<a target="_blank" class="gemiano gemiano-large center" href="' + download(lastItem) + '&dl=1">Download file</a><br>')
     $('.content').append('')
     display.push(lastItem)
     chk = true
     inject();
   } 

   if (chk) {
     // insert to database
     jQuery.post("includes/insert.inc.php", {media: display, url: '<?php echo $urlx; ?>'}, function(data) {
       console.log('done')
     }).fail(function() {
       console.error('error')
     })
   }

 })
```

ad.php

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:block"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-7777093434100866"
    data-ad-slot="9204444187"
    data-ad-format="auto"
    data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: Just dumping that in there obviously creates invalid JavaScript code.

Comment: sorry, I'm new in this, but can I use this <?php include("./inc/ad.php");?> in JS to call a file?

Comment: I assume in javascript you can only "embed php" by making ajax call and inserting resulted html to page. But in your php file there is nothing from php itself (no calculations, variables etc.), it is just piece of html+javascript. So it may be better to insert this part in javascript, call to php is not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a string like any other literal content you append:

```
.append('<?php include("./inc/ad.php");?>')
```

Obviously this only works at all if the JavaScript is within a .php file as well (otherwise the PHP code in there won't actually be executed).

Comment: I added $('.content').append('<?php include("./inc/ad.php");?>') , but it didn't work

Comment: Define "didn't work" please. What actual result did you get? What debugging did you do? It's very hard to help if you don't describe the issue clearly.

Comment: all the javascript code appears on the page to my visitors, instead of showing the ad